# In R, how do I combine two XML documents into one document?

Tags: r, xml

I'm querying data from an XML-based API. The API responses are paginated, so I have to make a bunch of queries to get the full data set.

Using `read_xml` from the `xml2` package, I can easily make each request and save it as an XML document, but I've been having trouble figuring out how to use the library to combine them into one document. (I would like to do this so I can make the Xpath queries I need to make once instead of 50 times.)

I've tried creating a new blank document and adding the nodes of others as elements, but the `xml_add_child` nor the `xml_add_sibling` functions will take a second document as an argument, and neither seem to like being passed the result of an `xml_find_all` query. (They complain about not being able to work with references.)

So, I'm stumped.

(Note: I've also not had any success in discovering how to do this with the original `XML` package.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some trial and error, I've figured out how to do this with the `xml2` package.

Let us consider the simple case of two very simple XML documents we'd like to combine together.

```
doc1 <- read_xml("<items><item>1</item><item>2</item><items>")
doc2 <- read_xml("<items><item>3</item><item>4</item><items>")
```

(Note: where the documents come from don't matter, the argument to `read_xml` is anything it can read.)

To combine them together, simply do the following:

```
doc2children <- xml_children(doc2)

for (child in doc2children) {
    xml_add_child(doc1, child)
}
```

Now when you look at doc1 you should see this:

```
> doc1
{xml_document}
<items>
[1] <item>\n  1</item>
[2] <item>\n  2</item>
[3] <item>\n  3</item>
[4] <item>\n  4</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the XML package to initialize an empty document with `<root>` and iteratively append other XML content using `addChildren()` method from the root of each XML.

```
library(XML)

doc = newXMLDoc()
root = newXMLNode("root", doc = doc)

# LOOP THROUGH 50 REQUESTS
lapply(seq(50), function(i) {
    # PARSE ALL CONTENT
    tmp <- xmlParse("/path/to/API/call")

    # APPEND FROM API XML ROOT
    addChildren(root, getNodeSet(tmp, '/apixmlroot'))
})

# SAVE TO FILE OR USE doc FOR FURTHER WORK 
saveXML(doc, file="/path/to/output.xml")
```

*I cannot find a counterpart method in xml2 as its `xml_add_child` requires a character string not node(s).*

Comment: Thanks.  This is confusing me as xml_add_child help indicates that .value is a "node or nodeset to insert" but I get "Error: `.value` must be a character" when I try to insert a nodeset.  Discussed here: https://github.com/r-lib/xml2/issues/170

Comment: I think you meant to ask this on accepted solution above as I used the `XML` package and not `xml2`.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I was agreeing with the problem you identified with xml2.