# Convert list of xml_node to xml_document

Tags: r, xml, purrr, xml2

I have a list of xml_node items (`nodes_list` in the below reprex) which I would like to combine into a single xml_document with a root node (`bookstore_doc` in the below reprex).

My current solution is to create a `xml_new_root()` and iterate through my list of xml_node items with `xml_add_child()`. While this works, it's very slow! It took over 9 hours for about 6,000 nodes. I imagine this is in part due to the for loop, which I tried to replace with `purrr::map()`, `purrr::walk()`, or `sapply()` but couldn't those get to work. I'm guessing that there is a more computationally efficient way to approach this than iteratively going through the list of xml_node items, but I'm not sure what, since I'm still new to working with xml.

I'd appreciate any ideas on how to more efficiently convert a list of xml_node items to a single xml_document.

Thank you for your time and advice!

```r
library(xml2)

# Create data for minimal reproducible example
text_1 <- "
  <book>
    <title lang='en'>Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
"

text_2 <- "
  <book>
    <title lang='en'>Learning XML</title>
    <price>39.95</price>
    info
  </book>
"

node_1 <- xml_find_first(read_xml(text_1), "//book")
node_2 <- xml_find_first(read_xml(text_2), "//book")

nodes_list <- list(node_1, node_2)

# Current method for generating xml_document
bookstore_doc <- xml_new_root("bookstore")

for (book in nodes_list) {
  xml_add_child(bookstore_doc, book)
}
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>
Book nodes from https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_nodes.asp

**Related SO question**
[In R, how do I combine two XML documents into one document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461907/in-r-how-do-i-combine-two-xml-documents-into-one-document)

Answer (score 1):

One option rather than adding nodes one by one is to build the desired document structure as an R list, then convert this to an xml document. The key is to ensure the nodes are all named:

```
node_names <- rep("book", length(nodes_list))
as_xml_document(list(books = setNames(lapply(nodes_list, as_list), node_names)))
#> {xml_document}
#> <books>
#> [1] <book>\n  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>\n  <author>J K. Rowling</author>\n  ..
#> [2] <book><title lang="en">Learning XML</title><price>39.95</price>\n    info\n  </book>
```